# Late night travel on a Sunday in Barcelona

Tags: public-transport, spain, barcelona

Does the transport from the airport run on a Sunday night (about 9pm) going to Tetuan, Marina, or Arc de Triomf?

**One of our guide books incorrectly said the airbus did not run on a Sunday, hence this question.**

Answer (score 7):

I live in Barcelona, and on Sunday there is metro until midnight and buses [(nitbus)](http://www.emt-amb.com/principales/busquedanitbus.aspx) all night, saturdays and holidays all night too. However, you can find all the schedule for the metro in Barcelona [here](http://www.tmb.cat/en/horari-metro-bus-barcelona).

You will be fine going from the airport to any place at the hour you arrives.

As for your specific trajectory, I recommed you to take the renfe from the Airport to **Passeig de Gracia**, and make a connection to the `L2 direction *Badalona Pompeu Fabra*` and leave in **Tetuan** (if want to go there), or from the airport take the renfe to *Sants Estació*, make a connection to the `L1 direction *Fondo*` and leave in **Arc de Triomf** or **Marina**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

http://www.barcelona-tourist-guide.com/en/airport/transport/barcelona-airport-bus-aerobus.html

this one runs a bit past midnight.

http://www.barcelona-tourist-guide.com/en/airport/transport/barcelona-airport-bus-tmb.html

Cheaper. Runs till 23:50

Now the metro runs to the airport too. http://www.barcelona-tourist-guide.com/en/faq/airport/transport/metro/operating-hours-for-metro-to-barcelona-airport.html in general up to midnight.

There are http://www.renfe.com/EN/viajeros/cercanias/barcelona/index.html trains as well also up to midnight.

Past midnight there is some night bus but that wasn't the question :)

Answer (score 0):

For easy travel, maybe not fastest.

(The AirBus runs 7 days of the week, however some guide books **incorrectly** says it does not run on a Sunday.)

- Take the AirBus (very well singed posted at the airport), you pay the driver, get a return ticket if using it on the way back, as it saves a bit.
- Get off at the last stop (Catalunya) where most people get off. The buses wait for some time before returning to the airport, therefore this stop is hard to miss. (We made the error of getting off at Espanya, and then have lots of steps both up and a long walk to get to the metro line.)
- Then use the metro that runs until midnight.
- When you exit the metro station, it can take some time to work out where you are as most stations have many exits. Next to some of the exits are maps showing the local roads. Yet as the metro stations tend to be across roads at crossings, it can be hard to work out the way to walk. (I may take a compass next time!)